# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BrowserWindow') at application startup

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

and thank you for having a look at my question/problem.

I am following a tutorial by DesignCourse on Youtube and I am at my wits end, I rewatched it but nothing is different from what I can tell. The tutorial is from 2017 and I know that in later versions of electrode some things were turned off by default.

Down to the matter at hand, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BrowserWindow') is the error. With this code I am attempting to open a new page, however even though main.js code works fine with no isses, when I attempt to load the new javascript file to open a new window, it does not like the new code on start up of the application at all for some reason.

I have gone through quite a few forums with no luck. Originally I had `required` is not defined error for the first two lines of index.js, I fixed that with nodeIntegration: true, enableRemoteModule: true, and contextIsolation: false.

Anyway, 'BrowserWindow' is undefined which makes no sense to me as it already worked in main.js

I am sure it is something simple that I am over looking. I have tried deleting the package-lock.js and node_modules and reinstalled them using npm install but neither worked with no errors later being caused to the application.

The dependancies and versions:
"electron": "^23.2.0"
"@electron/remote": "^2.0.9"
"electron-context-menu": "^3.6.1"

node v18.15.0
npm v9.5.0

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const shell = require(`electron`).shell;
// const contextMenu = require('electron-context-menu'); //context menu

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        title: `Crypto Currency Page`,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        //frame: false,
        // titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }
    })

    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    //custom menu setup
    let menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {

            label: `Menu`,
            submenu: [

                {
                    label: `Adjust Notification Value`
                },

                {
                    label: `CoinMarketCap`,
                    click() {

                        shell.openExternal(`http://coinmarketcap.com`)//this opens a new tab in the browser

                    }
                },
                { type: `separator` }, //this adds a separator in the menu
                {
                    label: `Exit`,
                    click() {
                        app.quit();

                    }
                },
            ]
        },

        {

            label: `Info`,
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: `Hooray`
                },


            ]


        }

    ])

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    win.loadFile('./src/index.html')
}



app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow()
        }
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

index.js - this is the code that only gets to line 3 before checking out

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;

const notifyBtn = document.getElementById("notifyBtn");

notifyBtn.addEventListener(`click`, function () {

    const modalPath = path.join(`file://`, __dirname, `add.html`);

    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        title: `Idk this page will load some day`,
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js'),
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }

    });

    win.on(`close`, function () { win = null });
    win.loadURL(modalPath);
    win.show();

})
```

With this code I am attempting to open a new page, however even though main.js code works fine with no isses, when I attempt to load the new javascript file to open a new window, it does not like the new code at all for some reason.

Comment: Can you please confirm if your `index.js` file is being loaded by your `index.html` file or another file?

Comment: Hi there, yes the index.html file loaded the index.js file

Comment: I know it is a tutorial you are following but its general design is old and outdated. Electron has moved foward a great deal from then. Some tips: Where possible you should set `nodeIntegration` to `false`. Additionally, in Electron v23.2.0 the `enableRemoteModule` option does not exist. Use of the 3rd party [@electron/remote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote) module is still possible but is not recommended (even by its developer). Use of Electron IPC is really the way to go. Lastly, creation of (your second) Electron window(s) should really be placed in your main process.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have taken a step back from electrode for the time being to learn more advanced JS and soon React due to its up to date documentation and industry standard practises. But! I will return with the knowledge you have bestowed onto me. YOU HEAR ME ELECTRODE! I WILL NOT QUIT!